# Can we have two versions of openssl library in yocto

Tags: yocto

There are two openssl recipes in `poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl`

- openssl10_1.0.2u.bb
- openssl_1.1.1g.bb

When i build the image with openssl, then libcrypto.so.1.1 is only present. I want to have both versions of libcrypto into rootfs. I tried adding `IMAGE_INSTALL += "openssl10"`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to install `libcrypto10` package.

Else than reading the recipe, you can find this info by running `oe-pkgdata-util find-path "*libcrypto*"`.